# Solve 4 equations using Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve $4$ systems of equations with $4$ unknowns. There are some trig involved and I keep getting error

> "Solve::ifun: inverse functions are being used by Solve."

Please help me to solve these equations with correct coding. I tried this.Do I need the "degree"?I'm trying to solve for $x,y,z$ and $t$. $t$ in degrees.

```
Solve[
 {-xcos[30 °] + ycos[° t] == 0, 
  xsin[30 °] - ysin[° t] == 50, 
  -ycos[° t] + zcos[40 °] == 0, 
  ysin[° t] + zsin[40 °] == 125}, {x, y, t, z}, ]
```

Comment: `xcos` should actually be written as `x*Cos` or `x Cos`. All trigonometric functions assume their input is in radians. So, indeed, you need Degree if the input is in degrees.

Comment: BTW The message you got is not an error message but a warning. You'll always get this if you or the functions you use try to invert functions that are not bijective. The results returned may not be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Your code re-done:

```
s = 
  Solve[{
    -x Cos[30 °] + y Cos[t ° ] == 0, x Sin[30 °] - y Sin[t ° ] == 50, 
    -y Cos[t ° ] + z Cos[40 °] == 0, y Sin[t ° ] + z Sin[40 °] == 125}, 
    {x, y, t, z}];
```

*N.B.* When entering a *Degree* token adjacent to a symbol, you *must* separate it from the symbol with a space. In the case of a numeric value, the space is optional.

You'll find the solution has a conditional part, with a constant `C[1]`, so pick some value(s) as desired to get specific solutions:

```
s1 = N[s /. C[1] -> 1]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 142.661, y -> -125.376, z -> 161.281, t -> 189.796}, 
>  {x -> 142.661, y -> 125.376, z -> 161.281, t -> 369.796}}
> ```

Verification

```
{-x Cos[30 °] + y Cos[t ° ], x Sin[30 °] - y Sin[t ° ],
 -y Cos[t ° ] + z Cos[40 °], y Sin[t ° ] + z Sin[40 °]} /. s1 // Chop
```

> ```
> {{0, 50., 0, 125.}, {0, 50., 0, 125.}}
> ```

Comment: @m_goldberg: Re: *N.b* edit - *N.b.*: "Nota Bene* abbreviations of *N.b*, *N.B.*, *n.b* are all standard. ;-}